# error Build: File 'COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY.ts' not found in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I received the following error after the repair of visual studio 2015.

```
Error       Build: File 'COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY.ts' not found.
```

`COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY.ts` is not from my Git repo. Other files in the Git repo have not changed. What could it be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found answer here, it works for me: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7445

the error indicates that there is a mismatch between your targets (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets) and the tasks dll (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\TypeScript.Tasks.dll); this would be an issue with the installer not handling a specific order of installing different versions.

Can please try:

- uninstall TS 1.8.* from Add/Remove Programs
- uninstall TS 1.7.* from Add/Remove Programs
- make sure the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript is empty, if not remove it manually
- install TS 1.7.6 again, you should see the folder created in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript

Comment: This also works for TypeScript 2.0. I was stuck for days with this error and this is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 9):

For me the solution was to move the folder at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript
```

and overwrite everything there.

Comment: I am installing 1.8.4 after installing 1.7.6 and this worked for me

Comment: this worked for me.  Simple copy/paste.  no uninstall/reinstall

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7445#issuecomment-219073705) helped me a lot, I could solve my problem this way

> When I removed "COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY" from the
>   line Configurations="$(TypeScriptBuildConfigurations)
>   COMPUTE_PATHS_ONLY" in the file Microsoft.TypeScript.targets, my
>   problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

The steps mentioned above will not guarantee to fix your issue. After following the steps mentioned above I was keep getting the same compiler error.
I restarted my machine after "uninstall and install" operation but no luck.
Finally, I found that instead of doing all these from control panel we have to do it from package manager (Right Click on solution and select "Manage Nuget packages for solution.."
First uninstall the TS package for your project from package manager and then install the package and build.

[Img of project setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3as3r.png)

Answer (score -1):

I was using the VS 2015 update_1 and type script version 1.8
For me it was solved by updating VS 2015 in update_3
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt752379.aspx